# Add table row dynamically in apps script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script

I have a table with two rows: first row is header and second row is like this...

```
<tr>
      <td><b>1</b></td>
      <td><input type="date" id="dt" name="dt"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="tmStart" name="tmStart"></td>
      <td><input type="time" id="tmEnd" name="tmEnd"></td>
      <td><select id="ddlTrainType" name="ddlTrainType"><option>Select Training</option></select></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="txtLoc" name="txtLoc"></td>
      <td><select id="ddlProg" name="ddlProg"><option>Select Program</option></select></td>
      <td><select id="ddlTrainMod" name="ddlTrainMod"><option>Select Module</option></select></td>
      <td><select id="ddlTrainName" name="ddlTrainName"><option>Select Trainer</option></select></td>
      <td><select id="ddlStat" name="ddlStat"><option>Pending</option><option>Completed</option><option>Cancelled</option></select></td>
</tr>
```

> Note: all **select** tags drop-downs are populated from another google spreadsheet.

Now, on button click(button like **add row**), I want to append a similar row like above to this table.

Not only add a row, but also, in the end, let's say there are 5 rows in total and **submit** is clicked, then I want to store all 5 rows in a Google Spreadsheet.

Any ideas how to do this?

I already tried adding row with the help of code.gs file and reconstructing template using `HtmlService.createTemplate`. But this can only be used in `doGet(e)` I guess and cannot work with js button action.

Let's say we create such dynamic table, but even after that, how do we pass all the table data from javascript to code.gs file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay after some rigorous Googling and testing so many scenarios, I myself came up with the solution, hope it will help someone someday. Here it goes:

1. To append row dynamically, I used this:

`$('#trainingTable > tbody:last-child').append(newRow);`

Here, `#trainingTable` is id of my table. `newRow` was like this:

```
var newRow = '<tr id="rowToClone">'
      + '<td><b>'+ rowCount +'</b></td>'
      + '<td><input type="date" id="dt'+rowCount+'" name="dt'+rowCount+'"></td>'
      + '<td><input type="time" id="tmStart'+rowCount+'" name="tmStart'+rowCount+'"></td>'
      + '<td><input type="time" id="tmEnd'+rowCount+'" name="tmEnd'+rowCount+'"></td>'
      + '<td><select id="ddlTrainType'+rowCount+'" name="ddlTrainType'+rowCount+'"><option>Select Training</option></select></td>'
      + '<td><input type="text" id="txtLoc'+rowCount+'" name="txtLoc'+rowCount+'"></td>'
      + '<td><select id="ddlProg'+rowCount+'" name="ddlProg'+rowCount+'"><option>Select Program</option></select></td>'
      + '<td><select id="ddlTrainMod'+rowCount+'" name="ddlTrainMod'+rowCount+'"><option>Select Module</option></select></td>'
      + '<td><select id="ddlTrainName'+rowCount+'" name="ddlTrainName'+rowCount+'"><option>Select Trainer</option></select></td>'
      + '<td><select id="ddlStat'+rowCount+'" name="ddlStat'+rowCount+'"><option>Pending</option><option>Completed</option><option>Cancelled</option></select></td>'
      + '</tr>';
```

Here `rowCount` is used to uniquely identify rows. It is defined as below:

```
var rowCount = $('#trainingTable tr').length;
```

2. Now comes the question of populating drop-downs from spreadsheet. For that I simply used same function which was used earlier but this time I passed `rowCount` as well.

Now, our table is created properly and is fully dynamic. Now, the question was to pass latest table data to **gs** file. For that, I used the following:

```
var entireForm = document.getElementById("MY_FORM_ID");
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showSuccess).GS_FUNCTION(entireForm);
```

Now when I used `Logger.log` to check the form values, I got entire latest object of the form on **gs** file side. Hence, problem solved!